# How to build a dynamic form

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, microsoft-forms, power-automate

I have a need to create a form that will collect data, optionally email someone based on the contents of that data, and put the data into a list.

My thought was MS Forms -> Power Automate Flow -> Sharepoint Online

Unfortunately, some of the questions that get asked will depend on the data that is sitting in a sharepoint list.  (for example, we want a drop down of 'tags'... but need people to be able to add their own 'tag' via a text field.)

How can I 'feed' custom questions into MS forms dynamically?  Should I be looking at a different product?

If MS Forms can't do this, do sharepoint 'forms' (that allow fully-dynamic content) exist in the o365 environment?

Thank you.

Comment: MS Forms is not a topic for this site. This site is for SharePoint questions. You may want to try the TechCommunity for MS Forms: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/ct-p/MicrosoftForms

Comment: Okay.   I figured there was a stack exchange venue for this question.  Apologies for being wrong.  If needed,  will repost without ms forms references.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MS Forms does not have the capability, you can do some branching logic within the Form, but only based on previous questions within the same Form.

I think you would be better off building a form in [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/).  The interface to build is not nearly as quick and easy as MS Forms, but you have a lot more direct integration with other O365 data sources, including SharePoint and Power Automate.  You can show and hide controls based on just about any logic, including user properties or values looked up from SharePoint.